# resizing div following filtering div contents

Tags: jquery, html, search, filter, resize

I am using jquery filters to narrow down products.

All products have their own divs but are all inside of one "large div".

When a filter is used, the divs for the products which don't meet the filter criteria disappear. However, the height of the "large div" does not change. How would we go about making the height of the "large div" resize automatically?

To clarify, before the filter is applied, there are many products, so the height of the div is very large. Once a filter is applied, the number of products in this div decreases, but the height does not change. It leaves it with a bunch of empty space at the bottom.

As soon as the browser window is resized a little bit, it triggers the height of the "large div" to adjust to the filtered products. But how can we accomplish this without the need of having to resize the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far?. Share your code please

Comment: Hi Marco, here's what I have so far:  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#filter1button").click(function()
{$(".productsa, .productsb, .productsc").hide();
$(".productsd").show();
});
});
</script>

Comment: The .products classes are all classes for divs within the large div (we'll name it #largediv)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the following Code Snippet `#largediv` resizes as desired (yellow area). So there must be something else in your code adding that extra height.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#filter1button").click(function () {
        $(".productsa, .productsb, .productsc").hide();
        $(".productsd").show();
    });
});
```

```css
#largediv {
    background: yellow
}

#largediv div {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="filter1button">Filter Class D</button>
<div id="largediv">
    <div class="productsa">
        <b>Product Class A</b>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in dictum elit, ut interdum mi. Duis viverra orci sit amet neque lobortis placerat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="productsb">
        <b>Product Class B</b>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in dictum elit, ut interdum mi. Duis viverra orci sit amet neque lobortis placerat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="productsc">
        <b>Product Class C</b>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in dictum elit, ut interdum mi. Duis viverra orci sit amet neque lobortis placerat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="productsd">
        <b>Product Class D</b>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in dictum elit, ut interdum mi. Duis viverra orci sit amet neque lobortis placerat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="productsa">
        <b>Product Class A</b>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in dictum elit, ut interdum mi. Duis viverra orci sit amet neque lobortis placerat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="productsb">
        <b>Product Class B</b>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in dictum elit, ut interdum mi. Duis viverra orci sit amet neque lobortis placerat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="productsc">
        <b>Product Class C</b>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in dictum elit, ut interdum mi. Duis viverra orci sit amet neque lobortis placerat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="productsd">
        <b>Product Class D</b>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque in dictum elit, ut interdum mi. Duis viverra orci sit amet neque lobortis placerat.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks again for your response. You are correct, in theory it should work fine, however it seems a slider plug-in I am using is interfering. If you want to have a look at what I'm working with, you can check out https://banffcarteblanche.com/index.php/activities-test-page/ . When one of the icons is clicked, it hides certain columns in the slider, but the large grey div doesn't resize until you manually resize your browser window. Any ideas on how to write some code to resize it automatically on click of the icons? Many thanks!